# Prebid not attempting to set key values in ad targeting

Tags: javascript, prebid.js, header-bidding, prebid

I am trying to setup prebid on my website and using the sample code from prebid website. Currently i have appnexus and Adx on board, this is the flow in console:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJeVW.png

As you can see in above image that the flow is perfect except there is no attempt to set key values.

Expected flow should be like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WnVD.png

I don't know whats is causing this.

Below is my code:

```
        var unit_728x90 = [
            [728, 90],
            [600, 300]
        ];
        var unit_300x250 = [
            [336, 280],
            [300, 250],
            [300, 100],
            [320, 50]
        ];
        var unit_320x50 = [
            [320, 50]
        ];
        var unit_300 = [
            [300, 250]
        ];
        var PREBID_TIMEOUT =2000;
        var FAILSAFE_TIMEOUT = 3000;
        var ASSERT_TIMEOUT = 1000;

        var adUnits = [{
                code: '21791303143/upl_belowslidem_300x250',
                mediaTypes: {
                    banner: {
                        sizes: unit_300x250
                    }
                },
                bids: [{
                    bidder: 'appnexus',
                    params: {
                        placementId: 17076422
                    }
                }]
            }     
        ];

        var googletag = googletag || {};
        googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || [];
        googletag.cmd.push(function() {
            googletag.pubads().disableInitialLoad();
        });
         if(window.screen.width < 769){
            googletag.cmd.push(function() {

             });
         }else{
            googletag.cmd.push(function() {
            googletag.defineSlot('/21791303143/upl_belowslidem_300x250', unit_300x250, 'div-side').addService(googletag.pubads());
            googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
            googletag.enableServices();
            });
        }

        var pbjs = pbjs || {};
        pbjs.que = pbjs.que || [];
        pbjs.que.push(function() {
            pbjs.setConfig({ 
                priceGranularity: "high",
                enableSendAllBids: false,
                useBidCache: true
            })
        });

        pbjs.que.push(function() {
            pbjs.addAdUnits(adUnits);
            pbjs.requestBids({
                bidsBackHandler: initAdserver;
                 }
            });
        });

         function initAdserver() {
            if (pbjs.initAdserverSet) return;
            pbjs.initAdserverSet = true;
            googletag.cmd.push(function() {
                pbjs.que.push(function() {
                    pbjs.setTargetingForGPTAsync('div-side');
                    googletag.pubads().refresh();
                });
            });
        }
        setTimeout(function() {
            initAdserver();
        }, FAILSAFE_TIMEOUT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally this is because DFP has already set targeting and chosen a winner as well as rendered an Ad for your slots by the time your Prebid app has passed bids to setTargeting. Are you sure you are using `disableInitialLoad` as well as `enableSingleRequest` functions with DFP/GAM? Search for these on their [Basic Example page](http://prebid.org/dev-docs/examples/basic-example.html) to see how they are loading their DFP. If you can send over a link to your page and we could tell you exactly the issue from there too.